# How do I optimize my MATLAB polynomial reducibility program?

Tags: matlab

Suppose I have the polynomial `f(x) = x^n + x + a`. I set a value for `n`, and want `0 <= a <= A`, where `A` is some other value I set. This means I will have a total of `A` different polynomials, since `a` can be any value between `0` and `A`.

Using MATLAB, I'm finding the number of these A polynomials that are reducible. For example, suppose I set `n=5` and `A=10^6`. That would tell me how many of these `10^6` polynomials of degree 5 are reducible. I've done this using a loop, which works for low values of `A`. But for the large values I need (ie. `A=10^6`), it's taking an extremely long & impractical amount of time. The code is below. Could someone please help me meaningfully optimize this?

```
syms x 
A = (10^6);
n = 5;
s = 0;
a = s:A;
total = 0;
parfor i = 0:A

 if feval(symengine, 'irreducible', x^n + x+i) == false
      total = total + 1;
      i
  end
end
total
```

Comment: seems like optimization problem but it is not clear what you are looking for...
Can you edit the question, please?